# Jquery Datatables multiple rows selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way by clicking on (for example) row 1 and then row 5. To select from(between) 1 to  row 5. I try from this [demo](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html). Any idea?

Comment: @OffirPe'er No.

Comment: The demo I attached solved your problem, use the ctrl key to accomplish what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the **select** option, Like in the **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/J77wMoFD1LOqTUND4XVw?p=preview)**
I have made for you.
Make sure to include:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js" </script>
```

and add `select: true` to the table init.

Answer (score -1):

Try holding down the shift key while clicking.

Comment: I want this with Javascript.